# MP4 video not play on browser

Tags: javascript, css, html, mp4

Im creating a video manage.
But when the video will load. Do not load.
Im using video.js but local files not load.

Test here:
http://thatupload.com/videos/video.MP4

in localhost have the same error.

this error: http://i.snag.gy/Q7A2r.jpg

Thanks for all

Comment: I recently worked with integration of video js plugin with rails application.. i gave original video url without converting it in background and it worked for me

Comment: NO... it is not working

Comment: Ok thanks. 
im not understand why this happens ...

Comment: update question with the relevant code.

Comment: Check your video encoding. It needs to be `H.264`

Comment: mine is h.263! How to change to h.264?

Comment: your video URL itself is not working,, how will video JS play video ?

Comment: There are plenty of freeware converters. I personally use FormatFactory. This still won't work on 100% of all browsers but on most of them and the rest will revert to the `videojs` flash player.

Answer (score 0):

compare with this working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akhildave/vCQEN/1417/),, hope this helps you out

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
preload="auto" width="640" height="264" data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["flash"] }'>
  <source src="rtmp://cp67126.edgefcs.net/ondemand/&mp4:mediapm/ovp/content/test/video/spacealonehd_sounas_640_300.mp4" type='rtmp/mp4'>
```

Comment: upload some small size video and check its working. Your uploaded file is very big in size its still downloading